# programmatically manage db connection while using datasets

Tags: asp.net, dataset, database-connection

I was just thinking if there was a way to programmatically open and close connections to the database via the dataset classes we've added into the project.

I am trying to avoid one specific problem. Assume there is an `EmployeeTableAdapter`. It has two methods `IsValid(string EmployeeID)` and `HasDepartmentAccess(string EmployeeID, string DeptID)`. Afaik each of these methods, open a connection, does data retrieval, and then closes it.

The opening and closing of the connection is done internally. I kind of want to override this, and close the connection upon a page unload event which (I'd manually register it with the datadapter class somehow).

Comment: What problem are you trying to avoid by doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have connection pooling enabled (or disabled, because it's enabled by default) I don't recommend you to close a connection manually. Because now on every "close" connections doesn't becomes closed, they just becomes marked as closed and returns to pool and becomes to be ready to be used into a next query.

Read more at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx)